# Loopback 4 deployment in heroku, lb-tsc not found error

Tags: node.js, typescript, strongloop, loopback4

I'm trying to deploy a loopback 4 app into heroku. 
But after publishing it npm-start command not working in heroku console.
its throwing sh: 1: lb-tsc not found.
package.json is as follows

```
"devDependencies": {
"@loopback/build": "^3.0.0",
"@loopback/eslint-config": "^5.0.0",
"@loopback/testlab": "^1.10.0",
"@types/node": "^10.17.6",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.10.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.10.0",
"eslint": "^6.7.2",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^6.7.0",
"eslint-plugin-eslint-plugin": "^2.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-mocha": "^6.2.2",
"source-map-support": "^0.5.16",
"typescript": "~3.7.3"},
"scripts": {
    "build": "lb-tsc",
    "build:watch": "lb-tsc --watch",
    "clean": "lb-clean dist *.tsbuildinfo",
     .......
    "lb-tsc": "lb-tsc",
    "postinstall": "npm run lb-tsc"
  }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have exactly the same problem

Comment: no. still, I'm having the error

Comment: See my answer below, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When **heroku** runs node application the value of  process.env.NODE_ENV is "production" you may check it from heroku terminal bash by typing **node** and then **process.env**
And this means that dev dependencies are not resolved.

Below steps work fine to me

1. Open package.json file copy all from dev dependeny section and paste it to dependency section in package.json
2. git add . then git commit and then  git push heroku master

**Another Solution:**
After pushing files to heroku using git push heroku master go to heroku terminal from https://dashboard.heroku.com/  and start console and then run command **node dist/index.js**  so this command will start loopBack application make sure dist folder is available.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a `Procfile` in the root of the project containing `web: node .` fixed this for me. Without it, Heroku will default to starting the app by calling `npm run` which tries to run the build process, and since `@loopback/build` is set up as a dev dependency by default, this results in the `lb-tsc not found` error.

Comment: this should be the correct and accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried many solutions and it works when I do the following things :

Make sure heroku has a nodeJs builpack running in your terminal

`heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs`

Then, create a Procfile to the root of your project and add :

`web: node index.js`

Finally add a heroku-postbuild script :

`"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"`

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it in the command line:
`npm i -g @loopback/cli
npm i -g @loopback/build`

I'm using it in macos from command line.

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere to replace `web: slc run` with `web: node .` in Procfile, and it seems to be working in Heroku! I do see the explorer and can use all the endpoints.

I mention this also in this Github issue:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback.io/issues/810